# In textarea autoscroll to bottom doesn't work when typing after webkit-transform

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, iscroll4, iscroll

I use iScroll.js in my phonegap application. When I typing message in text area a text doesn't scroll to the bottom automatically in webkit. When I disable `-webkit-transform` for scrolling div autoscroll works.

I tried to set `-webkit-transform: none !important` for text area, but it didn't give any results.

Does anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is webkit bug. As a workaround you can turn off `-webkit-transform` style from the child of iScroll element while textarea is in focus and immediately set `scrollTop` value to avoid jumping of scrolled content. And then return original styles on blur. Basic code to handle this will look like this:

```
// find iScroll block and its child
var scrollBlock = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var iscrollBox = scrollBlock.children[0];
var lastOffset = 0;

// remove translate styles on focus
var focusHandler = function() {
    var styleAttr = getComputedStyle(iscrollBox)['-webkit-transform'];
    var scrolledOffset = new WebKitCSSMatrix(styleAttr).f;

    iscrollBox.style.webkitTransform = '';
    scrollBlock.scrollTop = -scrolledOffset;
    lastOffset = scrolledOffset;
};
var blurHandler = function() {
    scrollBlock.scrollTop = 0;
    iscrollBox.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(0px, '+lastOffset+'px)';
};

// attach focus/blur handlers
var textareas = scrollBlock.querySelectorAll('textarea');
for(var i = 0, l = textareas.length; i < l; i++) {
    textareas[i].onfocus = focusHandler;
    textareas[i].onblur = blurHandler;
}
```

If you don't like such JavaScript fix - consider using CSS3 property `webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` instead of iScroll. It also has some pitfalls, but doesn't have such problem with textarea.